# Sony Vaio can't install bootloader

Tags: sony-vaio

When trying to install Ubuntu or Win10 with my Sony Vaio laptop, it complains that the bootloader can't be installed. It seems to be a software or partitioning problem. What can I do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backup all your data to an external hard drive and try deleting every partition you can find on your Sony Vaio before beginning the installation. You can do that with a Ubuntu live USB. Just search for Gparted and do the changes there. Don't forget to apply before closing it.